# mod_perl redirect

Tags: redirect, mod-perl

So I'm working in a mod_perl environment, and I want to know what the best way is to redirect to a new url. I know in CGI Perl you use print "Location:...", however I've come to find that usually there are better ways to do things in mod_perl, but I can't seem to find anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use Apache2::Const -compile => qw(REDIRECT);
sub handler {
  my $r = shift;
  $r->headers_out->set( Location => $url);
  $r->status(Apache2::Const::REDIRECT); #302
}
```

This is the answer for how to properly redirect in mod_perl2